# How to click on a flash object

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on a flash object. This is my javascript code below, currently, which is not working. I am not too familiar with js, hence, please bear with me.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelectorAll('a[title='Banner - Flash']').click();");
```

A screenshot of the page html:

[image]

Comment: They reason you may have got a downvote because you posted the screenshot instead of the `html`. Some users on SO intend to downvote because of not having the ability to play around with the actual `html`. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `querySelector()` not `querySelectorAll()`. `querySelectorAll()` is plural and hence it returns all `elements` matching the `cssSelector`. You also have to be careful about the selector and make sure it returns ONLY the intended element.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('a[title='Banner - Flash']').click();");
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to grab an iframe. The code below works just fine!!!

```
driver.switchTo().frame("rmf_iframe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:gotoAdFormat(130);')]")).click();
```